# Group Policy: How to comment on each setting?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, configuration-management

I am looking for a way to comment on each and every setting that can be made within a GPO. Unfortunately things like user logon scripts and security settings and some more can not be commented.

Is there some enterprise ready tool or method available for this? The catch-word is change- and configuration management here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Document them in an external document would be my suggestion. Make a document with a section for each GPO and in each, document what settings are in use and why.